# Clearing Firefox cache from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have added the following line in my Pre-deployment section (SharePoint) to clear my IE cache. Is there any way to clear Firefox cache as well?

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a perfect solution but maybe it will help You. Save this command as .bat file:

> del /q /s /f
>   %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\$profile$\Cache\*

Where `$profile$` is Your firefox profile folder.

Comment: Is this a standard path for all firefox versions?

Comment: Yes, for Windows Vista and above.